# Oracle INSTRING function equivalent in postgres with 4 parameters

Tags: postgresql, position

How can I create this INSTRING logic in postgres.
Code : INSTR(NAME,',',3,1)
Is there any way to add as many parameters with POSITION fn as in Oracle's INSTRING fn.
Thanks!

Comment: please explain what that function does. You can't expect that everybody that knows Postgres also knows all Oracle functions and their variations.

Comment: This function starts searching for the first occurence of comma from the third position of the string and gives the position.

Comment: There's a useful chapter on that in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-porting.html#:~:text=Example%C2%A043.11%20shows,your%20porting%20easier.) on just that, with a PL/pgSQL implementation of Oracle's `INSTR`.